# Subsite creation trigger approval workflow and Workflow manager utility

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager, approval

**First question.**
When you reach Site Contents you see all subsites and you can create new ones. I want to trigger a workflow that ask someone to approve subsites creation, the subsite is not create as long as it has not been approved.
Does someone knows how to perfom this ?

**Second question.** Everywhere i see that you MUST configure workflow manager if you use Sharepoint 2013. Thing is i dont have it and i can still create workflow. What is the point of workflow manager ? what is it used for ? what is its utility ? Everybody says "install it" but nobody explains why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding your first question there is a similar thread at MSDN - [Approval workflow for creating a subsite](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a0befad-5357-41e2-bcf0-f659bd0d4c25/approval-workflow-for-creating-a-subsite?forum=sharepointcustomization)
2. If you don't install workflow manager, the workflows will be 2010 style workflows. If you want to create 2013 style workflows, you need to configure the workflow manager. I have written a blog post on this at - [Workflows in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio](http://www.thesharepointguide.com/workflow-sharepoint/) Check the link to technet article in the first paragraph to learn more about the workflow manager and SharePoint  2013 style workflow architecture.